# how to display submenu in the sidebar using HTML, css and Js

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, sidebar

I need a help, I am making a web page in which I need to create a responsive sidebar with sub menu.
So far I have done the html and css part I also have added a js to it but still it is not working also I want to add the responsiveness to this so that when the user click a hamburger menu it opens the sidebar and when user click beside the sidebar it close it (I want to close my sidebar on clicking beside it and not by using cancel button). To be more precise I am crating a clone of myntra website in mobile view.
below is my code please help if you can thank you.
html:

```
<div class="sidebar-ul">
                <ul class="menu-list">
                    <li class="menu-items">
                        <a href="" class="item-link">
                            <div class="toflex">
                                <span>Men</span>
                                <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="drop-list" style="padding-left: 20px;">
                            <li class="drop-item">
                                <a href="" class="item-link">
                                    <div class="toflex">
                                        <span>Topwear</span>
                                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="drop-menu-list" style="padding-left: 20px;">
                                    <li class="menu-item">
                                        <a href="" class="item-link">
                                            <div class="toflex">
                                                <span>T-shirts</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="menu-item">
                                        <a href="" class="item-link">
                                            <div class="toflex">
                                                <span>Casual Shirts</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="menu-item">
                                        <a href="" class="item-link">
                                            <div class="toflex">
                                                <span>Formal Shirts</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="menu-item">
                                        <a href="" class="item-link">
                                            <div class="toflex">
                                                <span>Sweatshirts</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="menu-item">
                                        <a href="" class="item-link">
                                            <div class="toflex">
                                                <span>Jackets</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="menu-item">
                                        <a href="" class="item-link">
                                            <div class="toflex">
                                                <span>Rain Coats</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="drop-item">
                                <a href="" class="item-link">
                                    <div class="toflex">
                                        <span>Indian & Festival Wear</span>
                                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="drop-item">
                                <a href="" class="item-link">
                                    <div class="toflex">
                                        <span>Bottomwear</span>
                                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="drop-item">
                                <a href="" class="item-link">
                                    <div class="toflex">
                                        <span>innerwear & Sleepwear</span>
                                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="drop-item">
                                <a href="" class="item-link">
                                    <div class="toflex">
                                        <span>Plus Size</span>
                                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="drop-item">
                                <a href="" class="item-link">
                                    <div class="toflex">
                                        <span>Footwear</span>
                                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-items">
                        <a href="" class="item-link">
                            <div class="toflex">
                                <span>Women</span>
                                <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-items">
                        <a href="" class="item-link">
                            <div class="toflex">
                                <span>Kids</span>
                                <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-items">
                        <a href="" class="item-link">
                            <div class="toflex">
                                <span>Home & Living</span>
                                <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-items">
                        <a href="" class="item-link">
                            <div class="toflex">
                                <span>Beauty</span>
                                <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="user-specific-links">
                <ul class="specific-list">
                    <li class="specific-item">
                        <a href="">Myntra Studio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="specific-item">
                        <a href="">Myntra Mall</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="specific-item">
                        <a href="">Myntra Insider</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="specific-item">
                        <a href="">Gift Cards</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="specific-item">
                        <a href="">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="specific-item">
                        <a href="">FAQs</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="specific-item">
                        <a href="">Legal</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar .sidebar-ul {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaec;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.sidebar .image-signUp-box{
    position: relative;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-signup {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 14%;
    right: 18%;
}

.sidebar .login-link {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #ff3f6c;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-ul > ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
}
.sidebar-ul .item-link {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #3e4152;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-ul .toflex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 14px 20px;
}

.sidebar .user-specific-links {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.sidebar .specific-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
}

.sidebar .specific-item a {
    display: block;
    color: #282c3f;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar .drop-list a {
    font-weight: 400;
}
 ul.drop-list {
            display: none;
        }

        ul.drop-menu-list {
            display: none;
        }
```

Javascript:

```
var mainDrop = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-items");
            var i;

            for (i = 0; i < mainDrop.length; i++) {
                mainDrop[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                    this.classList.toggle("active");
                    var mainDropContent = this.children(".drop-list");
                    if (mainDropContent.style.display === "block") {
                        mainDropContent.style.display = "none";
                    } else {
                        mainDropContent.style.display = "block";
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: where have you put the `sidebar-ul` div?

Comment: I Have put it in a div called as sidebar

Comment: I updated my code for js but again the submenu is not showing so this is my updated code in the next comment

Comment: var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("item-link");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
                dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                    // this.classList.toggle("active");
                    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
                    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
                        dropdownContent.style.display = "none"; } else {
                        dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
                    }
                });
            }